Problems with IBus Pinyin
In some system apps, there are problems in the video, and can't switch Chinese/English using shift key.
https://youtu.be/6AvGB9x5SLg

Please review the info on this site https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask After edit your question and add some details.  There is nothing you have given so far that can be used to offer an answer.
